# How to get value from map of Pair and Object in java

Tags: java, dictionary, oop, hashmap

I want to return map value by using position which is the key of the map
I have this function :

```
Map<Pair<Integer , Integer> , Unit> map = new HashMap<>();
public Unit getUnit(Pair<Integer , Integer> position){
    return map;
}
```

Comment: Is this Java or javaFX?

Comment: Explain this `Pair` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd get the value like you would with any other key, using [`Map.get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get-java.lang.Object-):

```java
public Unit getUnit(Pair<Integer, Integer> position) {
    return map.get(position);
}
```

Comment: But be careful not to change the Pair values or it won't work or you could get the wrong value.  It would be best if the Pair objects were immutable.  And Pair **must** override equals and hashCode.

Comment: I'd assume this is the `Pair` in JavaFX (since I can't seem to find a pair elsewhere and OP doesn't mention making their own class), which is immutable and does override equals and hashCode.